# navigator.share does not work properly on Windows 10 Chrome + Edge browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, web-share

I use web share API, according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/web-share) website it should be supported on Windows OS (browsers Chrome and Edge). But when I try to use `navigator.share({ title: 'Title' });` I receive an empty window with the message.

[image]

If I use Mac OS Safari it works fine and shows all ways to share the content, for example.

[image]

My question is why on Windows I see the empty window and how to fix it.

Comment: Did you read and [supporting documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Share_API)? For instance, the [`canShare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/canShare) method, and what OSes need to provide to browsers in order to be able to share things? For instance, when I try to run the [live example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#examples), I get an error.

Comment: I've checked the support in the documentation. It says the same that the feature should work on Windows in Chrome and Edge browsers. I suspense that I send wrong parameters. I need to add text and url in the body of the share methdo.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Windows required url parameter to be sent with title. If you change it to `navigator.share({ title: 'Title', url: 'url' });` It will start working on Windows and MacOS.